# Spark counter has no spark when fire is put nearby

Tags: electrostatics, radiation, ionization-energy

With a positively charged gold leaf electroscope,

- $\alpha$ radiation: gold leaves fall rapidly
- Fire: gold leaves fall rapidly
- $\beta$ radiation: no observable change

With a high-voltage spark counter, however,

- $\alpha$ radiation: causes spark
- Fire: no observable change
- $\beta$ radiation: no observable change

Why is the ionizing power of fire strong enough to make the gold leaves fall but not strong enough to cause sparks in a spark counter?

Comment: I wonder whether the different behaviour of the detectors is due to their different geometries. Around the top cap of the GLE there is quite a wide region where ions from the fire will be accelerated by the electric field and will cause the GLE to lose its charge. In the spark detector maybe the region is much smaller. I say 'maybe' because I've never seen a spark detector! Nor do I know the position of the  source (or the fire) in relation to the detectors.